# Getting a jqgrid action helper to work

Tags: zend-framework, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, helper

After a few searches I came across a [jqgrid action helper](http://www.grasvezel.nl/Blog/view/196/jqgrid_Action_helper.html) that I could include into my Zend MVC.
However after downloading the source and trying to use it I get this error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getActionController() on a non-object in
.....
\Controller\Action\HelperBroker.php on line 299
```

Here is an excerpt of the helper

```
class My_Helper_jqgrid extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract {
    /**
     * Instance of the config file.
     *
     * @var Zend_Config_Ini
     */
    protected $_config = null;

    /**
     * The instance of the database
     *
     * @var Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract
     */
    protected $_db = null;

    /**
     * The provided view
     * 
     * @var Zend_View_Interface
     */
    protected $_view = null;

    /**
     * The options provided to this helper
     * 
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_options = array();

    /**
     * @var Zend_Loader_PluginLoader
     */
    public $_pluginLoader;  

    public function __construct(Zend_View_Interface $view = null, array $options = array()){
        //$this->_db = Zend_Registry::getInstance()->get("db");         
        $this->_db = 'mato';            
        $this->_pluginLoader = new Zend_Loader_PluginLoader();
        $this->_view = $view;           
        $this->_options = $options;             
    }

    /**
     * Strategy pattern: call helper as broker method
     * 
     * @param string | Zend_Db_Table_Select $sql
     * @param string | array $columns
     */
    public function direct($sql, $columns = "*", $tableId = "id", array $options = array()) {

        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer')->setNoRender();
        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('layout')->disableLayout();

        $this->_options = $options;     
        $page = $this->getRequest()->getParam("page", 1); // get the requested page 
        $rows = $this->getRequest()->getParam("rows", 20); // get how many rows we want to have into the grid 
        $sidx = $this->getRequest()->getParam("sidx", $tableId); // get index row - i.e. user click to sort 
        $sord = $this->getRequest()->getParam("sord", "asc") == "desc" ? "DESC" : "ASC"; // get the direction
        $response = new stdClass(); // The response object which will be translated into a json object
        ...............
        ................
        return json_encode($response);      
    }   
}
```

In my controller

```
print $this->_helper->Jqgrid("SELECT * FROM artist", 
        array("artist_code","artist_name","artist_album"), "id");
```

In my bootstrap

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath(
        APPLICATION_PATH . "/controllers/helpers", "My_Helper");
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It may help to post some example code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this: http://zendframework.com/issues/browse/ZF-7027

I just googled for your error so I'm not sure if the link above applies.

Comment: I checked out that link and realised it could be avoided by setting my cases to match.Thanks.